# Усобица и междоусобица

Tags: синонимы

Есть выражение "междоусобные войны", а есть "усобица" или "междоусобица".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем разница между этими понятиями? Или это все синонимы?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведенные слова, действительно, являются синонимами, но "усобица" - это устаревшее слово.

Из словарей:

УСОБИЦА. УСОБИЦА, -ы, жен. ( стар.). Междоусобная вражда, борьба. Княжеские усобицы.

УСОБИЦА, -ы; ж. Устар.= Междоусобие и Междоусобица. Усобицы князей. Не принимать участия в усобицах между кем-л.